# Why I can not create a file from a path is actually exists in Android Work Profile?

Tags: android, android-work-profile

**UPDATE**
I have solved the problem with following code. Basically it creates a file and copy stream from original one into new one, so that our app has a copy of file to be safely upload to the server.

```
try {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(videoUri, "r", null);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    file = new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), getFileName(videoUri));
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to select a video from gallery and upload to the server while my app is working in work profile.
When app is working in private profile everything is working great but when I run the app in work profile my app is crashing.

`File file = new File(videoPath);`  is crashing the app.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid file:
 /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20200511_121657.mp4
```

the app is working on work profile and granted for permissions at runtime:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Somehow it does not find the files that in user gallery only in work profile since I can upload same file with same code in private profile.
Thanks in advance!

**Update**:
App is crashing while I upload video to AWS.

```
public TrasferObserver upload(String bucket, String key, File file, ...) {
  if (file == null || file.isDirectory() || !file.exists()) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file: " + file);
  }
  //some other aws code
}
```

Well, what I did is basicly I get uri from picker and
then I get video path from my function.

```
  public String getPath(Uri uri, Context context) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
      int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

and then create file from path with `File file = new File(videoPath);` and call upload method.

I have tested it with `new File(uri.getPath());` but both does not work.

one more comment: code is working properly in private profile.

Comment: `File file = new File(videoPath); is crashing the app.`. No. That statement will not crash your app. Look further for the statement that does it.

Comment: well you're right. it get exception from aws transfer utility. 

if (file == null || file.isDirectory() || !file.exists()) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file: " + file);
        }

Comment: and it means file is not exists.

Comment: `want to select a video from gallery and upload to the server`. If you let the user select a file then you will obtain a nice uri in onActivityResult. Not that path. Please explain. Show your code.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: It is a bad idea trying to convert an uri to a file system path. Use the uri directly. Change the upload function to use an Uri instead of a File instance.

Comment: I agree and I can not since it's a AWS function. 
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility.upload(TransferUtility.java) that's why I am making that strange conversion :) by the way, thanks for your time.